# Detect a specific shape using machine learning

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

The problem is detecting a specific convex shape (somehow elliptical) through training a supervised model. As input I have many traces of two dimensional points.

What I currently do is :

- compute the convex hull of the shape and use the following as features :

  - area/parameter of the convex hull of the shape
  - average distance between the shape points and its convex hull
- train a labeled set of shapes on multiple models (logistic regression, naive Bayes, random forests)
- apply the model to test data

The results I am getting shows a bad accuracy. The problem seems to resemble shape recognition in computer vision. Is there any suggestion for enhancing maybe the features or using a totally different approach?

Comment: for the visual problem convolutional neural nets in deep learning are state of the art. This technique became instant hit because models using deep neural nets in visulization problems beat machine learning models for the same even with years of research. So look for tensor flow, keras, caffe etc. with convolution neural nets

Comment: The way you prepare your data, extract features, etc... will change everything on your result, this part of pre-processing is crucial. And as abhiieor said, neurals network can be a good solution.